# Why is this join table always doing posts_tags?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, relationship, rails-migrations

When I use the following:

```
class CreateJoinTableTagsPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :tags, :posts do |t|
        t.index [:tag_id, :post_id]
    end
  end
end
```

or the following:

```
class CreateJoinTableTagsPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :posts, :tags do |t|
        t.index [:post_id, :tag_id]
    end
  end
end
```

I always get a table that is `posts_tags` and as a result helper methods in the posts model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blogs

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, join_table: 'tags_posts'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, join_table: 'categories_posts'
  has_many :comments

  validates :title, presence: true

  def has_tag?(tag_name)
    tag == tag_name
  end

  def assign_tag=(tag_name)
      tag = Tag.find_by(name: tag_name) || Tag.create(name: tag_name)
      self.tag = [tag] if tag
  end

end
```

Don't actually work. As you can see the `assign_tag` method wont actually work, tests that are done as such:

```
it "should create a page for a post" do
  @post.assign_tag = 'Sample Tag'
end
```

fails because relation tags doesn't exist. I believe this can be solved by creating the appropriate join table of `tags_posts` instead of the one it always creates `posts_tags`

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`create_join_table`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_join_table) uses the lexical order of the arguments to name the table.

You can override this using a `table_name` option:

```
create_join_table :posts, :tags, table_name: 'tags_posts' do |t|
    t.index [:post_id, :tag_id]
end
```